# Argument 2: cannot convert from 'float; to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Lines 17 and 20 are what's giving me a real problem
I have tried changing line 17 to `float radius = new (0.125f, 0, 0);`
however that didn't yield any positive results.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static LayerMask layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Default");

    public static bool CapsuleCast(this Rigidbody rigidbody, Vector3 direction)
    {
        if (rigidbody.isKinematic)
        {
            return false;

        }

        float radius = 0.125f;
        float distance = 0.375f;

        RaycastHit Hit = Physics.CapsuleCast(rigidbody.position, radius, distance, direction, layerMask);
        return Hit.collider != null && Hit.rigidbody != rigidbody;
    }

}
```

Comment: A `float` is a single number, how would `new (0.125f, 0, 0);` even have meaning here?

Comment: A `CapsuleCast` requires 2 points (as per the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.CapsuleCast.html) - you are only providing one. There is no overload that would calculate the second point from a "distance" argument

Comment: FYI we cannot see what *your* line 17 and 20 are. Please add a comment to the problem lines

Comment: _Just like the age-old dream of turning lead into gold, sadly one cannot turn `float` into `Vector3`._  At least without an explicit conversion operator perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you originally came from a SphereCast.

A [`Physics.CapsuleCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CapsuleCast.html) requires as parameters either

```
Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2, float radius, Vector3 direction, float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction = QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal);
```

or

```
Vector3 point1, Vector3 point2, float radius, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction = QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal);
```

where

```
point1     The center of the sphere at the start of the capsule.
point2     The center of the sphere at the end of the capsule.
```

so there is no overload accepting the parameters you are providing

```
Vector3, float, float, Vector3, (int)LayerMask
```

---

Now you can either pass in the same position again

```
if(!Physics.CapsuleCast(rigidbody.position, rigidbody.position, radius, direction, out var hit, distance, layerMask)))
{
    return false;
}

return hit.rigidbody != rigidbody;
```

but that wouldn't make much sense to use the more expensive `CapuleCast` then.

Or directly rather use a [`SphereCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) which would result in the same

```
if(!Physics.SphereCast(rigidbody.position, radius, direction, out var hit, distance, layerMask)))
{
    return false;
}

return hit.rigidbody != rigidbody;
```